# Trying to figure out how to use recursions to get the same answer as another function

Tags: c++, math, recursion

I could use some help with my programming assignment. I need to use a recursion in order to make arithmetic_series = arithmetic_series_recursive. Right now my recursive function is not working properly. It only works up until the number three. The functions are supposed to take the input from the user and form a number based on the number of integers inside the number. IE if the user entered 3 it would be 1*2*3 = 6.

```
int arithmetic_series(int n){
    int total = ((n+1) * n )/ 2;
    cout << total << endl;
    return total;
}

int arithmetic_series_recursive(int n){
    if(n==1){
            return 1;
    }else{
    return n*arithmetic_series_recursive(n-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Odds are good your development environment came with a debugging tool. This might sounds like a dodge, but in the long run knowing how to use a debugger will make your life a lot easier. It is probably the number one programmer productivity tool.

Comment: Oh @FrançoisAndrieux you are completely right I don't know how I missed that. Do you have any idea how I could make it work with the sum as opposed to the product.

EDIT: NEVERMIND it was very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your first function finds the sum of integers from `1` to `n`. Your second function finds the product of the that range, or `!n`. I don't know of any simplification you could use in your first function.

If you meant to find the sum of the numbers, you can change the your second function to preform an addition :

```
int arithmetic_series_recursive(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n + arithmetic_series_recursive(n - 1);
    }

}
```